# Changing a navigation property on a detached entity which also has a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, navigation-properties

Consider the following POCO entity:

```
public class Produkt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code:

```
Product product;
Provider provider1;
Provider provider2;
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    provider1 = context.Provider.Add(new Provider());
    provider2 = context.Provider.Add(new Provider());
    product = context.Product.Add(new Product() { Provider = provider1 });
    context.SaveChanges();
}

// Imagine a GUI using product and provider1 and provider2 to display some data.
// Now the user changes the provider for the product.
product.Provider = provider2;

// Now the user presses the save button.
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;      // ERROR
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem here is that `product.ProviderId` is not getting updated, since the change happens while the entity is not attached to a context.
One obvious solution would be to keep the context open. However this seems like a bad idea if the whole user interaction can take a while.
Another solution would be to set `ProviderId` manually. This is very error prone, though.

What is the best approach to solve this problem?